# Как сделать внешний ключ?

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

В общем есть две таблицы в БД. MySQL

Первая:      
`id | name | lastname | surname | id_key |`

Вторая:       
`id_key | car | city|`

`id_key` без A.I. код состоит из шести цифр.

Мне надо, чтобы когда пользователь вводил код (`id_key`), в его таблицу, как бы заносились и та, другая, таблица.
Что для этого нужно? Создать из `id_key` внешний ключ, как?

Comment: Вы хотите спросить как в две таблицы добавить один и тот же ключ?

Comment: нет) id_key это первичный ключ, в одной таблице, как сделать из него еще внешний ключ для другой таблице, просто написать его имя?

Comment: А при чем тут эльфы?

Comment: Не обижайтесь, но Вам нужно научиться понятнее выражать свои мысли. Не понятно ничего.

Comment: кароч, как сделать внешний ключ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `table2` (`id_key`) SELECT `id_key` FROM `table1` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Так? Это при условии `id AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы создадите внешний ключ, ничего само собой вводиться не будет, просто появится связь.
Этого можно и не делать.
Просто потом, если вы, например, делаете админку к сайту, можете выводить в `<select></select>` только те данные из бд, которые можно туда вносить. В вашем случае там будут отображаться через цикл все ваши `id_key` из первой таблицы.